# Open source Android routing SDK

Tags: android, routes, openstreetmap, osrm

Well, I have implemented OpenStreetMap with OsmDroid SDK, but having trouble to find open source routing SDK for Android. I would appreciate any help on that.

> Note: I know OSRM-server implementation just works fine, but we have
>   server problem. And OSRM public servers gets down frequently, hence
>   not reliable for our use case.

***P.S. how frequently OSRM public server gets down?***

Comment: Why don't you install OSRM locally as suggested below?

Comment: Also have a look at other tools: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing#Libraries.2Fdevelopment_tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any public/free server is probably 'best effort' without guarantees. Only when there is a commercial option with a paid tier that you may be able to get a service level agreement (SLA) about how frequently the service is unavailable.

In short: Create your own OSRM-server implementation on hardware you pay for and maintain to get the availability you want.

Comment: Installing your own OSRM instance is actually very simple. See the [OSRM wiki](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki) for more information.

Comment: Yes, we implemented server version. And works perfectly.